# How to use predis in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redis

I'm using `codeigniter` framework.
I want to use `redis` on my project.

to do this I find this library:

```
https://packagist.org/packages/predis/predis
```

I installed it with composer.

now I want to use it:

```
  $client = new Predis\Client();
```

but I got this message:

```
Message: Class 'Predis\Client' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set the `$config['composer_autoload'] = true` in `application/config/config.php`

Also, CodeIgniter assumes that you have installed compsoer into the `application` directory. If you have installed it elsewhere (e.g. in the root directory of the project) you will need to set `$config['composer_autoload']` to the path of the composer vendor autoload.php file

**For example**

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = '/vendor/autoload.php';
```